# No matches the given query

Tags: python, django

Помогите исправить ошибку.

> Page not found (404)
> No Post matches the given query.
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/posts/2/
> Raised by:  blog.views.specific_post

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from . models import Post

def showblog(request):
    posts = Post.objects
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html',{'posts': posts})


def specific_post(request,post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    return render(request,'blog/specific_post.html', {'post':post})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from.import views


urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.showblog, name = 'showblog'),
    path('<int:post_id>/',views.specific_post, name='specific_post'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 300)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'event_images/')

    def get_summery(self):
        return self.text[:100]
```

Comment: У вас в базе данных присутствует пост с id2?

Comment: У меня есть два поста. Ни первый, ни второй не могу вывести, такая же ошибка.